Can I abort some of the attacks in a full attack action?
For example, when I encounter an NPC with Robilar's Gambit, I may wish to attack with my first 2 attacks and then skip my last 2 attacks so that I won't get AoOed with the attacks with low hit rate.
I see a potential solution that I may redirect my low-hit-rate attacks to the ground (or a block that nothing occupies it) but I still wonder if I can simply abort them.

Robilar's Gambit - Benefit:
At the start of your action, you can adopt a fighting stance that
exposes you to harm but allows you to take advantage of your
opponents' exposed defenses as they reach in to attack you. Anyone who
strikes at you gains a +4 bonus on attack rolls and damage rolls
against you. In return, they provoke attacks of opportunity from you
each time they swing. Resolve your attack of opportunity after your
foe's attack.


You can explicitly abort a full attack entirely after the first attack, and instead consider it a standard attack (freeing up your move action):

Deciding between an Attack or a Full Attack
After your first attack, you can decide to take a move action instead of making your remaining attacks, depending on how the first attack turns out. If you’ve already taken a 5-foot step, you can’t use your move action to move any distance, but you could still use a different kind of move action.

(Actions in Combat → Full Attack)
After the second attack (having locked in that this is a full attack), there is not an explicit statement one way or the other. However, a general principle of attacking applies:

You do not need to specify the targets of your attacks ahead of time. You can see how the earlier attacks turn out before assigning the later ones.

(ibid.)
Since you can target empty squares, you can easily “waste” your remaining attacks without risking any retaliation from the original target.
Since that is the case, I expect most DMs are also going to let you simply not make those attacks, since swinging at air like that is silly and doesn’t add anything to the game.
However, for completeness’s sake, let’s try to definitively answer that question. The full attack rules, frustratingly, don’t cover it—which means we have to start digging into individual sources of extra attacks. There are too many of those to really cover every single possible one, but I’ll cover some of the biggest ones:

Iteratives—ambiguous. The rule says only that “A second attack is gained […], a third […], and a fourth […],” without saying whether or not you’re required to use them when you full attack.

Two-weapon fighting—always optional, in that you can simply choose to not take the penalty and not get the benefit.

Improved Two-Weapon Fighting and Greater Two-Weapon Fighting—ambiguous, in the case where your first two attacks were your main hand attack and your offhand attack and you have thus conclusively engaged the two-weapon fighting option. The wording used in both feats is that you “get” an extra attack, which is similar to the “gain” wording from the iterative rules and equally ambiguous.


Haste—explicitly optional, you can decide to take the extra attack or not freely.

Whirling frenzy—explicitly something you “may” do, but when you’re making that choice is somewhat unclear. The wording is odd: it seems to suggest that you choose to gain the extra attack as you actually take that attack, but since the ability applies an attack penalty to all attacks that round, that would mean it’s applying a penalty retroactively. I guess you could decide to see if you only hit by 1 or 2 before deciding to take the penalty? But realistically, in practice, everyone is going to (and should) run this like two-weapon fighting, where you decide up-front to take the penalty.



Agreed - common sense also dictates that that remaining attacks can be ignored, otherwise characters would frequently be required to attack friendlies when an attack eliminates an enemy and there are no other enemy targets in range.  Not to mention the much rarer instance where characters are actually trying to take someone prisoner and do not want to take further attacks after rendering them unconscious.

@KerrAvon2055 Well, no, since they could attack an empty square, or the ground they’re standing on, or whatever. Characters being “required to attack friendlies” (or would-be prisoners) wouldn’t happen, it would just look silly.
